# Error: Invalid number of parameters (regular getter function). Got 0 expected 1!

Tags: truffle

Playing with drizzle, I am trying to use a getter for an uint variable campaignCounter, that gets incremented by 1 whenever a factory creates a new campaign.

Here is my component's code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ReadCounter extends Component {

  state = { dataKey: null};

  componentDidMount() {
    const { drizzle, drizzleState } = this.props;

    const contract = drizzle.contracts.CampaignFactory;

    const dataKey = contract.methods.campaignCounter.cacheCall({from: drizzleState.accounts[0], gas: 3000000});

    this.setState({ dataKey });
  }

  render() {
    const { CampaignFactory } = this.props.drizzleState.contracts;

    const campaignCounter = CampaignFactory.campaignCounter[this.state.dataKey];

    return <p> Number of campaigns {campaignCounter && campaignCounter.value}</p>;
  }
}

export default ReadCounter;
```

In the console i get the following error:

```
index.js:1375 uncaught at _callee at _callee 
 at contractsSaga 
 at takeEvery 
 at callCallContractFn 
 Error: Invalid number of parameters for "campaignCounter". Got 0 expected 1!
```

I have tried:

```
const dataKey = contract.methods.campaignCounter.cacheCall({from: drizzleState.accounts[0]});
```

and

```
const dataKey = contract.methods.campaignCounter.cacheCall();
```

For each case the same error is thrown.

My setup:

```
Truffle v5.0.18 (core: 5.0.18)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.16.0
Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37
```

Why does it expect a parameter for a getter function that only returns an uint? And what would be the parameter?

Thanks

---EDIT

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract CampaignFactory {

    address[] public deployedCampaigns;
    uint public campaignCounter;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {

        address newCampaign = address (new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender));
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
        campaignCounter++;
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the contract code (Solidity) for the function.

Comment: Sure - original post edited.

Answer (score 0):

> In smartcontract, method `createCampaign(uint minimum)` takes one
>   argument as uint input.

But during calling this method, You are not passing any uint argument.

`const dataKey = contract.methods.campaignCounter.cacheCall({from: drizzleState.accounts[0], gas: 3000000});`,

> So maybe your method calling should be like this:

```
const dataKey = contract.methods.campaignCounter.cacheCall(**uint parameter**, {from: drizzleState.accounts[0], gas: 3000000});
```

Comment: I am trying to use a getter for this variable: campaignCounter. It is not the issue with calling createCampaign method - this one works perfectly fine. Since campaignCounter is a public variable, it should have a getter, but it takes no arguments, hence I do not understand the nature of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, steps:

`const dataKey = contract.methods["campaignCounter"].cacheCall({from: drizzleState.accounts[1], gas: 3000000});`

I deleted .json files with contracts

Recompiled and migrated again.

Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you explain why your solution worked?